# API Mock de datos en Java Spring de Swagger

Tags: java, api, spring, swagger

haciendo un mock de los datos para una API me he encontrado con que teniendo los example en el Swagger editor, después de ejecutar el proyecto spring autogenerado por Swagger me encuentro con que el input del endpoint no es aceptable. Es un Json y el ejemplo lo autogenera como un string, por tanto debe utilizar caracteres de escape para incluir las comillas. Pero luego el servicio lo pega tal cual viene de allí, me explico:

Este es el swagger con las etiquetas example

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: Test
  version: 0.0.1
  title: Test
tags:
- name: Test
  description: ''
schemes:
- http
paths:
/testOperation:
   get:
     tags:
     - Test
     summary: Test
     description: Test
     operationId: testOperation
     produces:
       - application/json
     parameters:
       - name: testInput
         in: body
         schema:
           $ref: '#/definitions/testInput'
         required: true
     responses:
      '200':
        description: Successful operation
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/testOutput'
      '405':
        description: Error operation
definitions:
  testInput:
    type: object
    properties:
      mainId:
        type: integer
        example: 0001
      additional:
        type: array
        items:
          type: object
          properties:
            id:
              type: integer
              example: 1
            property1:
              type: string
              example: property1
            property2:
              type: string
              example: property2
        example:
          - id: 1
            property1: property1
            property2: property2
          - id: 2
            property1: property11
            property2: property22
  testOutput:
    type: object
    properties:
       id:
         type: integer
         example: 1
```

Y esta la linea de Java que maneja el example el servicio

```
   @ApiModelProperty(example = "
[{\"id\":1,\"property1\":\"property1\",\"property2\":\"property2\"},
{\"id\":2,\"property1\":\"property11\",\"property2\":\"property22\"}]", 
value = "")
```

Cuando lo subo y hago click en el ejemplo de entrada obtengo esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando lo ejecuto me da error porque no lee bien los caracteres de escape, mi pregunta es:

¿De que manera puedo escribir el string en Java para que reciba bien los example de Swagger? Tendría que devolver algo así al clickear en el ejemplo de entrada

```
{
  "mainId": 1,
  "additional": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "property1": "property1",
      "property2": "property2"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "property1": "property11",
      "property2": "property22"
    }
  ]
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No tengo mucha experiencia con Swagger pero parece ser que swagger no es capas de escapar los caracteres. Porque no intentas remover \ en el ejemplo del servicio.

Comment: Otro detalle seria revisar como estas configurando swagger dentro de tus clases de java

Comment: Quitando los / si que funciona pero claro yo quiero hacer click en el ejemplo  de entrada y que se me ponga automaticamente sin tener que estar quitándolos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta manera:

```
@ApiModelProperty(example="[{'id':1,'property1':'property1','property2':'property2'},{'id':2,'property1':'property11','property2':'property22'}]",value="")
```

Comment: No ha funcionado, me da este error:

"JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@722a6e92; line: 2, column: 17] (through reference chain: io.swagger.model.TestInput[\"additional\"])",

Comment: @Shassain me da el siguiente error, creo que está muy cerca tu solución "JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3d670c26; line: 2, column: 17] (through reference chain: io.swagger.model.TestInput[\"additional\"])",

Answer (score 0):

Tu POJO debe de quedar de la siguiente manera

```
@ApiModel(value = "persona")
public class Persona {

    @ApiModelProperty(name = "id", example = "1")
    private Integer id;

    @ApiModelProperty(name = "nombre", example = "nombre")
    private String nombre;

    @ApiModelProperty(name = "edad", example = "99")
    private Integer edad;   

}
```